# Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64 in XCode 4.6.2

Tags: c++, opencv, xcode4

I'm trying to write my first program using the OpenCV library. I'm using XCode 4.6.2 as IDE and I've already followed lots of tutorial to set up everything. This is my little piece of code

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <iostream>
#include "opencv2/core/core.hpp"
#include "opencv2/features2d/features2d.hpp"
#include "opencv2/highgui/highgui.hpp"
#include <opencv2/nonfree/nonfree.hpp>


using namespace cv;

int main(int argc, const char * argv[])
{

    String pathToImages="myPathToImages/";
    Mat img1=imread(pathToImages+"im1.jpg",CV_LOAD_IMAGE_GRAYSCALE);
    Mat img2=imread(pathToImages+"im2.jpg",CV_LOAD_IMAGE_GRAYSCALE);


    if( !img1.data || !img2.data )
    { std::cout<< " --(!) Error reading images " << std::endl; return -1; }

    //-- Step 1: Detect the keypoints using SIFT Detector

    cv::SiftFeatureDetector detector;


    std::vector<cv::KeyPoint> keypoints_1;
    std::vector<cv::KeyPoint> keypoints_2;


    detector.detect(img1, keypoints_1);
    detector.detect(img2, keypoints_2);

    //DO SOMENTHING

    return 0;
}
```

If I try to build it, I get this error:

```
Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
  "cv::FeatureDetector::~FeatureDetector()", referenced from:
      cv::Feature2D::~Feature2D() in main.o
  "cv::DescriptorExtractor::~DescriptorExtractor()", referenced from:
      cv::Feature2D::~Feature2D() in main.o
  "cv::SIFT::SIFT(int, int, double, double, double)", referenced from:
      _main in main.o
  "cv::FeatureDetector::detect(cv::Mat const&, std::vector<cv::KeyPoint, std::allocator<cv::KeyPoint> >&, cv::Mat const&) const", referenced from:
      _main in main.o
  "VTT for cv::SIFT", referenced from:
      cv::SIFT::~SIFT() in main.o
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

I'm using libstdc++ (GNU C++ standard library) as C++ standard library. Does anybody know what's wrong?

Comment: Did you add the relevant OpenCV libraries to your project ?

Comment: Yes, sorry I didn't write it. I've followed this guide firstly http://opencv.willowgarage.com/wiki/UsingOpenCVUnderOSX

Comment: OK - did you build the libraries yourself or did you use prebuilt libraries ? You need to check the architecture of the libraries - you can do this with the `file` command - they need to match the architecture of your build (x86_64 in this case, i.e. not i386).

Comment: Ok, I've got this result:
`libopencv_highgui.dylib: Mach-O 64-bit dynamically linked shared library x86_64`. I've built OpenCV using Macports.

Comment: OK - I think you also need to link the `libopencv_nonfree` library to get SIFT etc - just add it to your project like you did the other OpenCV libraries.

Comment: Yeah you're right! I've added 
`#include "opencv2/nonfree/features2d.hpp"
#include "opencv2/imgproc/imgproc.hpp"`
and it works fine! Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

I include the library

```
 #include <opencv2/nonfree/features2d.hpp>
```

instead of

```
#include "opencv2/features2d/features2d.hpp"
```

Here is the full libraries I used to apply SIFT detector

```
#include <opencv2/core/core.hpp>
#include <opencv2/highgui/highgui.hpp>
#include <opencv2/nonfree/features2d.hpp>
#include <opencv2/nonfree/nonfree.hpp>
#include <opencv2/opencv.hpp>
#include <opencv2/imgproc/imgproc.hpp>
```